# Testing React Hook Form with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql, react-testing-library

I have a Component with a form. `onSubmit` the form is using Apollo `useLazyQuery` to retrieve data based on form values.

In the component the form is handled by React Hook Forms and therefore, the `handleSubmit` is controlled by RHF.

`<FormContainer onSubmit={handleSubmit(collectFormData)} noValidate name='LoginForm'>`

Where the `collectFormData` send a GraphQL request as below.

```
const collectFormData: SubmitHandler<FormInput> = (formData) => {
  Validate({
    variables: {
        request: {
            type: 'NONS',
            firstName: formData.firstName,
            lastName: formData.lastName,
            rLOC: formData.bookingRef
        }
    }
  })
}
```

`const [Validate, { error, data }] = useLazyQuery(VALIDATE_ME)`

`component.spec.tsx`

```js
    import { MockedProvider, MockedResponse } from "@apollo/client/testing";
    import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
    import { act, fireEvent, getByLabelText, render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
    import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
    import { VALIDATE_PNR } from './../../gql/validate-pnr';
    import LoginForm from './login-form';

    const mocks = [{
        request: {
            query: VALIDATE_ME,
            variables: {
                firstName: "Buck",
                lastName: "Rogers",
                ID: "007BOND",
                type: "NONS"
            }
        },
        result: {
            data: {
                servicing: "0x0E5d7576Da82Bb8cC5E56214C6A7A7286D62DBDAc1"
            }
        }
    }];

    const renderComponent = (mockData: readonly MockedResponse<Record<string, string>>[] | undefined) => {
        return render(
            <MockedProvider mocks={mockData} addTypename={false}>
                <LoginForm />
            </MockedProvider>
        );
    }

    describe("Manage Bookinge", () => {
        describe("Login form", () => {

            it.only("should handle submit", async () => {
                const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
                const { getByRole } = renderComponent(mocks)

                await act(async () => {
                    fireEvent.input(getByRole("textbox", { name: /Booking reference \/ eTicket number Required/i }), {
                        target: { value: "007BOND" }
                    })
                    fireEvent.input(getByRole("textbox", { name: /First name Required/i }), {
                        target: { value: "Buck" }
                    })
                    fireEvent.input(getByRole("textbox", { name: /Last name Required/i }), {
                        target: { value: "Rogers" }
                    })
                    fireEvent.click(getByRole("button"))
                })

                await waitFor(() => {
                  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                        firstName: "Buck",
                        lastName: "Rogers",
                        ID: "007BOND",
                        type: "NONS"
                    });
                 });
            })
        })
    });
```

I am not able to pass the test. Errors with  below

```
                  No more mocked responses for the query: query Validate($request: IdentityAcquireTokenRequestInput!) {
      servicingValidate(request: $request)
    }
    Expected variables: {"request":{"type":"NONS","firstName":"Buck","lastName":"Rogers","ID":"007BOND"}}

    Failed to match 1 mock for this query, which had the following variables:
      {"firstName":"Buck","lastName":"Rogers","ID":"007BOND","type":"NONS"}
```

I  am not sure where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock the handleSubmit function. The function is inside the component you are rendering. From your code, I am not sure what the handleSubmit function does but there is probably a call being made to the back end inside the function. You can try to mock the call to the back end and check that it is call with the proper object.